# Uninstall ubuntu-desktop with unity, gnome etc

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10, but I was not happy with Unity, so I switched to Gnome 3 (classic).

This was also not the best for me, so I've tried LXDE. Again was not exactly, what I'm looking for. So I've tried Xfce. Now i'm happy with this solution. I don't need Gnome, Unity and LXDE anymore. I've tried to remove `ubuntu-desktop`. It was possible, but all applications, which are installed with Ubuntu are still here.

How can I remove Ubuntu/Gnome/Unity/LXDE completly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right link is http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce...

edit:

```
sudo apt-get remove adium-theme-ubuntu apg appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt at-spi2-core bamfdaemon banshee banshee-extension-soundmenu banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore baobab binfmt-support bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common checkbox checkbox-gtk cli-common compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf deja-dup duplicity dvd+rw-tools empathy empathy-common eog evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common example-content gbrainy gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.6 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-media gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-share gnome-utils-common growisofs gstreamer0.10-gconf gvfs-backends gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hwdata ibus-gtk3 indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-power indicator-session intel-gpu-tools libappindicator0.1-cil libarchive1 libatk-adaptor libatspi2.0-0 libaudio2 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda0 libcdio-paranoia0 libcdio10 libcompizconfig0 libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libdconf0 libdecoration0 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook1.2-12 libecal1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libexempi3 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-3-common libgail-common libgconf2.0-cil libgdata-common libgdata1.7-cil libgdata13 libgdiplus libgdu-gtk0 libgeoclue0 libgexiv2-0 libgif4 libgkeyfile1.0-cil libglew1.5 libglewmx1.5 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-data libgmime-2.4-2 libgmime2.4-cil libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgoa-1.0-0 libgpgme11 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgtk-sharp-beans-cil libgtk2.0-cil libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell3-0 libgudev1.0-cil libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libhyphen0 libidl0 liblaunchpad-integration1.0-cil liblircclient0 liblouis-data liblouis2 libmetacity-private0 libmhash2 libmission-control-plugins0 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-csharp4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmysqlclient16 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libnotify0.4-cil libnux-1.0-0 libnux-1.0-common liboauth0 liborbit2 liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libpth20 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtbamf1 libqtcore4 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libqtgui4 libquvi0 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librsync1 libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libstlport4.6ldbl libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtaglib2.0-cil libtelepathy-farsight0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtextcat-data libtextcat0 libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libubuntuone-1.0-1 libubuntuone1.0-cil libunique-3.0-0 libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity-misc4 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libyajl1 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 light-themes media-player-info metacity metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mousetweaks mysql-common nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share notify-osd notify-osd-icons nux-tools obexd-client overlay-scrollbar plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo protobuf-compiler pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf python-brlapi python-configglue python-dateutil python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-farsight python-indicate python-libproxy python-louis python-papyon python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pyinotify python-speechd python-support python-telepathy python-twisted-names python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-wnck qdbus qt-at-spi seahorse shotwell sni-qt ssh-askpass-gnome telepathy-butterfly telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thunderbird-gnome-support tomboy totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer unity unity-2d unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-scope-musicstores unity-services uno-libs3 ure vino whois wodim xdiagnose xfonts-mathml zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-extension-fts && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purekde for keeping only KDE
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu for keeping only Xubuntu

for a list of applications to remove for the various desktops.

To remove gnome,

```
sudo apt-get purge adium-theme-ubuntu aisleriot apg apport-gtk aptdaemon aptdaemon-data apturl at-spi2-core bamfdaemon banshee banshee-extension-soundmenu banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore baobab binfmt-support bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common checkbox checkbox-gtk cli-common compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf deja-dup desktop-file-utils dmz-cursor-theme doc-base duplicity empathy empathy-common eog espeak espeak-data evince evince-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common example-content file-roller firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support gamin gbrainy gcalctool gcc gcc-4.6 gconf2 gconf2-common gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 gir1.2-dee-0.5 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.6 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-unity-4.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gksu gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-common gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-utils-common gnomine gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-tools gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap guile-1.8-libs gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter humanity-icon-theme hwdata ibus ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase ibus-table indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-status-provider-mc5 intel-gpu-tools jockey-gtk language-selector-gnome launchpad-integration libappindicator0.1-cil libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libatk-adaptor libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libburn4 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcairo-perl libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcap2-bin libcdio-cdda0 libcdio-paranoia0 libcdio10 libcompizconfig0 libcroco3 libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libdconf0 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-1 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook1.2-12 libecal1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libespeak1 libevent-2.0-5 libevince3-3 libexempi3 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-3-0 libgail-3-common libgail-common libgail18 libgamin0 libgck-1-0 libgconf2-4 libgconf2.0-cil libgcr-3-1 libgd2-xpm libgdata-common libgdata1.7-cil libgdata13 libgdiplus libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgee2 libgeoclue0 libgexiv2-0 libgkeyfile1.0-cil libgksu2-0 libglew1.5 libglewmx1.5 libglib-perl libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgmime-2.4-2 libgmime2.4-cil libgnome-bluetooth8 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgoa-1.0-0 libgomp1 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrip0 libgssdp-1.0-2 libgstfarsight0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-sharp-beans-cil libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-cil libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell0 libgtkspell3-0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev1.0-cil libgupnp-1.0-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-3 libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libibus-1.0-0 libidl0 libido3-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libindicator3-6 libindicator6 libisofs6 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjte1 libkpathsea5 liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1 liblaunchpad-integration-common liblaunchpad-integration1 liblaunchpad-integration1.0-cil liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblircclient0 liblouis-data liblouis2 liblua5.1-0 libmetacity-private0 libminiupnpc5 libmission-control-plugins0 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-csharp4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil libnatpmp1 libnautilus-extension1 libnice10 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnotify-bin libnotify0.4-cil libnotify4 libnux-1.0-0 libnux-1.0-common liboauth0 libopencc1 liborbit2 liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libp11-kit0 libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-perl libpangomm-1.4-1 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpoppler-glib6 libportaudio2 libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libquadmath0 libquvi0 librarian0 libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-style-human librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librsync1 libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libstartup-notification0 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libt1-5 libtaglib2.0-cil libtelepathy-farsight0 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libubuntuone-1.0-1 libubuntuone1.0-cil libunique-1.0-0 libunique-3.0-0 libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity-misc4 libunity6 libutouch-geis1 libuuid-perl libvte-2.90-9 libvte-common libvte9 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwnck-common libwnck22 libxklavier16 libxres1 libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzephyr4 light-themes lightdm linux-headers-3.0.0-12 linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev media-player-info metacity metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd notify-osd-icons nux-tools onboard oneconf overlay-scrollbar pinyin-database pkg-config plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-1-gnome protobuf-compiler pulseaudio-module-gconf python-appindicator python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon-gtk python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-brlapi python-configglue python-dateutil python-defer python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-farsight python-gconf python-gnomekeyring python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-ibus python-indicate python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-louis python-notify python-openssl python-pam python-papyon python-piston-mini-client python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pyinotify python-serial python-speechd python-support python-telepathy python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-virtkey python-vte python-webkit python-wnck qt-at-spi rarian-compat rdesktop seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell simple-scan sni-qt software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk speech-dispatcher ssh-askpass-gnome system-config-printer-gnome telepathy-butterfly telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support tomboy totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk ubufox ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer unity unity-2d unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-scope-musicstores unity-services update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vinagre vino whois xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xul-ext-ubufox yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-extension-fts zenity zenity-common && sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop sudo apt-get remove adium-theme-ubuntu aisleriot apg apport-gtk aptdaemon aptdaemon-data apturl at-spi2-core bamfdaemon banshee banshee-extension-soundmenu banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore baobab binfmt-support bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common checkbox checkbox-gtk cli-common compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf deja-dup desktop-file-utils dmz-cursor-theme doc-base duplicity empathy empathy-common eog espeak espeak-data evince evince-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common example-content file-roller firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support gamin gbrainy gcalctool gcc gcc-4.6 gconf2 gconf2-common gedit gedit-common geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 gir1.2-dee-0.5 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.6 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-unity-4.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gksu gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-common gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-utils-common gnomine gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-tools gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap guile-1.8-libs gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter humanity-icon-theme hwdata ibus ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase ibus-table indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-status-provider-mc5 intel-gpu-tools jockey-gtk language-selector-gnome launchpad-integration libappindicator0.1-cil libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libatk-adaptor libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libburn4 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcairo-perl libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcap2-bin libcdio-cdda0 libcdio-paranoia0 libcdio10 libcompizconfig0 libcroco3 libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libdconf0 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-1 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook1.2-12 libecal1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libespeak1 libevent-2.0-5 libevince3-3 libexempi3 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-3-0 libgail-3-common libgail-common libgail18 libgamin0 libgck-1-0 libgconf2-4 libgconf2.0-cil libgcr-3-1 libgd2-xpm libgdata-common libgdata1.7-cil libgdata13 libgdiplus libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgee2 libgeoclue0 libgexiv2-0 libgkeyfile1.0-cil libgksu2-0 libglew1.5 libglewmx1.5 libglib-perl libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgmime-2.4-2 libgmime2.4-cil libgnome-bluetooth8 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgoa-1.0-0 libgomp1 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrip0 libgssdp-1.0-2 libgstfarsight0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-sharp-beans-cil libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-cil libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell0 libgtkspell3-0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev1.0-cil libgupnp-1.0-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-3 libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libibus-1.0-0 libidl0 libido3-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libindicator3-6 libindicator6 libisofs6 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjte1 libkpathsea5 liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1 liblaunchpad-integration-common liblaunchpad-integration1 liblaunchpad-integration1.0-cil liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblircclient0 liblouis-data liblouis2 liblua5.1-0 libmetacity-private0 libminiupnpc5 libmission-control-plugins0 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-csharp4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil libnatpmp1 libnautilus-extension1 libnice10 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnotify-bin libnotify0.4-cil libnotify4 libnux-1.0-0 libnux-1.0-common liboauth0 libopencc1 liborbit2 liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libp11-kit0 libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-perl libpangomm-1.4-1 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpoppler-glib6 libportaudio2 libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libquadmath0 libquvi0 librarian0 libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-style-human librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librsync1 libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libstartup-notification0 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libt1-5 libtaglib2.0-cil libtelepathy-farsight0 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libubuntuone-1.0-1 libubuntuone1.0-cil libunique-1.0-0 libunique-3.0-0 libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity-misc4 libunity6 libutouch-geis1 libuuid-perl libvte-2.90-9 libvte-common libvte9 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwnck-common libwnck22 libxklavier16 libxres1 libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzephyr4 light-themes lightdm linux-headers-3.0.0-12 linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev media-player-info metacity metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd notify-osd-icons nux-tools onboard oneconf overlay-scrollbar pinyin-database pkg-config plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo policykit-1-gnome protobuf-compiler pulseaudio-module-gconf python-appindicator python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon-gtk python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-brlapi python-configglue python-dateutil python-defer python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-farsight python-gconf python-gnomekeyring python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-ibus python-indicate python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-louis python-notify python-openssl python-pam python-papyon python-piston-mini-client python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pyinotify python-serial python-speechd python-support python-telepathy python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-virtkey python-vte python-webkit python-wnck qt-at-spi rarian-compat rdesktop seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell simple-scan sni-qt software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk speech-dispatcher ssh-askpass-gnome system-config-printer-gnome telepathy-butterfly telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support tomboy totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk ubufox ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer unity unity-2d unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-scope-musicstores unity-services update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vinagre vino whois xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xul-ext-ubufox yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-extension-fts zenity zenity-common
```

As you can see it is a long list, and likely could be simplified. You might wish to review the list and make sure there are no applications you wish to keep.

In addition, you may want to clean the configuration files in your home directory. (apt-get will not remove them).

If you are open to a few suggestions, if at all possible it is sometimes easier to run Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine, such as VirtualBox or KVM. You can try various packages or window managers and settle on a set you like.

You then install the appropriate version (l/x/k/ubuntu) on your hardware.

Comment: i will try to make the changes on my machine :) no risk no fun...the worst case - i must reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need to warn you that Ubuntu comes pre-packaged with both Unity and Gnome, and many applications & features depend on them or their libraries. If you decide to follow any of the instructions below, you're doing it at your own risk. If you decide to remove those packages, it may be a good idea to run a simulation first. It will give you an idea of what will be removed. You can run simulation by adding the **-s** flag, eg:

```
sudo apt-get -s --purge remove package_name
```

To get rid of Unity (Ubuntu's default session), you have to remove unity packages:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove unity*
```

As you may notice, there is a **--purge** flag. Adding it will also remove all associated configuration files.

To remove Gnome, your best option would probably be this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-*
```

Once again, I need to stress that many popular applications depend on Gnome's libraries and may refuse to work or be uninstalled along with Gnome.

Finally, in order to remove LXDE, your would probably run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove lxde*
```

As for the remaining applications, they are probably independent from Unity and you will have to remove them manually.

Comment: The question is, how to find, which packages must be removed, so i get clean xubuntu installation.